# Recast/Convert an 1D-array to a 2D one in C

Tags: c, pointers

In what follows I will be using the type definitions:

```
typedef float zreal;
typedef float* zvect;
typedef float** zmatr;
```

Assume that I have a `zvect` of total length `n` which I want to recast as a `zmatr` with `m` columns (assume of course that `m` divides `n`). The `zvect` "object" packs the values of `zmatr` row-wise, i.e. it is `a = [a1 a2 ... ap]` where `a` is of type `zvect` (thought of as a row vector). I need to convert this into a `zmatr` which would look like:

```
zmatr = [a1
         a2
         ...
         ap]
```

where `a1,...,ap` represent row-vectors. Is there a way to recast my `zvect` into a `zmatr` (without having to copy the values to a new entity)? What is the most efficient way to do so? Note that I wish to avoid accessing the values of the matrix using the vector directly, i.e. like `z[getIndex(i,j,ncols)];` where `getIndex(int i,int j, int ncols)` returns `i*ncols+j`. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

**Update:** It seems that the following code does the job:

```
zvect v;
create_vector(&v,100);

zmatr zm;
zmatr* matrix = &zm;

*matrix = (zmatr)malloc(sizeof (zvect) * 10);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    (*matrix)[i] = &(v[i*10]);
}
```

Comment: Casting the result of `malloc()` is not recommended.

Comment: You are using a pointer to a pointer to a pointer? And please highlight your question. Seems interesting,but i dont get anything out of it.

Comment: @Sibrajas Yes, you can call it like that. I would simply say, I'm using a pointer to a "matrix" (zmatr). Had I not introduced the type `zmatr` there would be a `float***` in the code above. I was looking for the **best practice** (if any) to convert a vector (a `zvect`) in my case (i.e. an array) to a matrix in an efficient way.  The hint by Dietrich Epp helped me jot down the code above (see the update in my question).

Answer (score 0):

These are very different, and cannot be converted:

```
typedef float* zvect;
typedef float** zmatr;
```

The type `zvect` is a pointer to a `float` or array of `float`.

The type `zmatr` is a pointer to a `float *`, or array of `float *`.

```
+-------+          +-------+
| zvect | -------> | float |
+-------+          | float |
                   | float |
                   | ...   |
                   +-------+

+-------+          +---------+           +-------+
| zmatr | -------> | float * | --------> | float |
+-------+          | float * | --        | float |
                   | float * |   \       | ...
                   | ...     |    \
                   +---------+     \     +-------+
                                    ---> | float |
                                         | float |
                                         | ...
```

So, the short story is that `zmatr` is **not** a 2D array, it is actually a 1D array which contains pointers to 1D arrays as elements.

Personally, I would stick with:

```
float elem = arr[i*ncols+j];
```

This is clear, concise, and explicit.

Comment: I am not envisaging something like `zmatr my_zmatr = (zmatr)my_zvect;` of course! But, how can I create a 2D array from an 1D array. I guess my `zmatr` needs only the addresses of the first elements from every element of every row...

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis: Yes, you can do that.  Of course, it will be much slower to access the elements.  And remember: `zmatr` **is not** a 2D array, it is a 1D array containing pointers.

Comment: Why should the access to a 2D array (or call it better an 1D array of pointers) be "much slower" compared to the case where an 1D array is used?

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis: Access to a 2D array will have the same speed as the 1D array.  **But,** the 1D array of pointers will be slower because you will have to access memory twice to fetch an element, instead of just once.  The second fetch is dependent on the first, this might cause a pipeline stall.

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis: Again, it's not a 2D array that we're talking about here.  It's a 1D array of pointers (I feel like I'm talking to myself, because nobody is listening to what I say...)

Comment: I incline to call it a 2D array because I can access its elements line `a[0][1]`, but you're right, it is an array of pointers.